# SharePoint workflow Status

Tags: workflow, status

I created a SharePoint designer workflow with name GraphicsWF. I want to get only the approved items, for that am using the query below

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="GraphicsWF" /><Value Type="WorkflowStatus">16</Value></Eq></Where>
```

I am not getting the values back as expected

Comment: <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="GraphicsWF" /><Value Type="WorkflowStatus">16</Value></Eq></Where>

Comment: You want only approved item from the list?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="WorkflowColumnName" /><Value Type="WorkflowStatus">16</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

Here is the list of the status codes used to maintain the workflow statuses.

```
Status                     -Value
Not Started                 0
Failed on Start             1
In Progress                 2
Error Occurred              3
Canceled                    4
Completed                   5
Failed on Start (retrying)  6
Error Occurred (retrying)   7
Canceled                   15
Approved                   16
Rejected                   17
```

Can you please post your complete code ?

Comment: @bhrati is the asker of the question. So I think he has tried that query with no success

Comment: Corrected my statement :)

Comment: <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="GraphicsWF" /><Value Type="WorkflowStatus">16</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy> this is the query i have to pass so that it cna pick only the approved items

Comment: Are you using C# code or Client object model ?

Comment: client object model to get the status of the itemwhere that list is having the designer workflow with associated task list

Comment: Please post your CSOM code as well.

Comment: Excellent work. Can you please provide official documentation link where this codes are defined?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it seems to appear on the first page of various search engine results. I do not think the information on the other answers is accurate, at least not according to Microsoft documentation. Please see the link

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowstatus?view=sharepoint-server

On it, the status values are

- 0 = Not Started
- 1 = Started
- 2 = Suspended
- 3 = Canceling
- 4 = Canceled
- 5 = Terminated
- 6 = Completed
- 7 = NotSpecified
- 8 = Invalid

Now, there is a UserStatus field that the developer can control but that can literally be a different set of values for every workflow if I'm not mistaken. Hopefully this will help someone in the future who has trouble finding the MS documentation straight away via a DuckDuckGo search!